# Footnote of a table in minipage

Tags: tables, captions, footnotes, minipage

There is some methods to write the table notation in the page's footer?
Something like the picture:
[image]

This is the code that I wrote for the table in the minipage:

```
                 \begin{minipage}{0.55\linewidth}   
                    \begin{tabular}{llr}
                        \toprule
                        Concetto & Tipo & Volume \\
                        \midrule
                        Bacheca      &    E     & \SI{6e8}{}\\
                        Pin             & A     & \SI{511e7}{}\\
                        Include            & A & \SI{2e2}{}\\
                        \bottomrule
                    \end{tabular}
                \end{minipage}
                \begin{minipage}{0.55\linewidth}
                    \begin{tabular}{clcr%
                            S[table-format=3]%
                            S[table-format=3]%
                            S[table-format=1.1]
                        }
                        \toprule
                        Operazione & Descizione & Tipo & Frequenza\\
                        \midrule
                        $2$ & Caricamento di una immagine               & I     & \SI{3e6}{}\\
                        $5$ & Salvataggio di una immagine                & I     & \SI{17,5e6}{} \\
                        \bottomrule
                    \end{tabular}
                \end{minipage}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to obtain.

Comment: @Bernard   How to set the caption of the table in the pages's footer

Comment: The document page footer, or at the bottom of the (global) page, just above the page number?

Comment: @Bernard       On the document page footer but only in this page

Comment: That's very unusual, as it will mingle with the page number in the plain page style.

Comment: @Bernard       The page number is on the top-right because the document class is `tufte-book`

Comment: You can use something like `\enlargethispage{somelength}`.

Comment: @Bernard       Can you see me how tu use this command?